# Decimal to binary conversion for large numbers in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have some large numbers in an Excel sheet and I want to convert them to binary.

e.g.

```
12345678  
965321458  
-12457896
```

Comment: Have you tried the `DEC2BIN` function?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109116/excel-using-dec2bin-with-large-numbers

Comment: `DEC2BIN` cannot handle number larger than 511.

Comment: user3103991, the information provided in the comment above by Taosique would normally be expected to be included by yourself to show some level of research effort on your part.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using DEC2BIN() with large numbers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109116/using-dec2bin-with-large-numbers)

Answer (score 69):

If we are talking positive number between `0` and `2^32-1` you can use this formula:

```
=DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT($A$1,256^3),256),8)&DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT($A$1,256^2),256),8)&DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT($A$1,256^1),256),8)&DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT($A$1,256^0),256),8)
```

**NOTE:** `=DEC2BIN()` function cannot handle numbers larger than 511 so as you see my formula breaks your number into four 8-bit chunks, converts them to binary format and then concatenates the results.

Well, theoretically you can extend this formula up to six 8-bit chunks. Maximum precision you can get in Excel is 15 (fifteen) decimal digits. When exceeded, only the most significant 15 digits remain, the rest is rounded. I.e. if you type `12345678901234567` Excel will store it as `12345678901234500`. So since `2^48-1` is 15 decimal digits long the number won't get rounded.

Comment: This is AMAZING, and strongly appreciated. Thank you!!!! And also to importantly note, SHAME ON YOU Microsoft...!

Comment: I am trying to use it, I tested it for the maximum number you indicated: `2^32-1`, and then check on [this page](https://www.binaryhexconverter.com/binary-to-decimal-converter), but I am not getting the same number. `BASE` has a higher limit: `2^53` so maybe for numbers greater than this one, a similar logic can be applied

Answer (score 45):

Perhaps a simpler option:

**Positive numbers only**, just use BASE (as in BASE2) for numbers between 0 to 2^53 in Excel 2013+.  Here are some examples:

```
=BASE(13,2)   # returns 1101

=BASE(3,2)    # returns 11

=BASE(3,2,4)  # returns 0011

Key: 3=number input  2=radix (binary)  4=Min_length--upvote "Micah Lindstrom's" comment for noticing
```

Credit for BASE answer goes here:
https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/69797/why-is-dec2bin-limited-to-82bits-in-an-32-and-64-bits-world/

**Negative numbers**: Come to think of it, negative numbers could be handled as well by building upon howy61's answer.  He shifts everything by a power of two (2^31 in his case) to use the 2's complement:

```
=BASE(2^31+MyNum, 2)
```

so (using 2^8 for only 8 bits):

```
=BASE(2^8+(-1),2,8)  # returns 11111111 

=BASE(2^8+(-3),2,8)  # returns 11111101
```

The numbers given by the OP requires more bits, so I'll use 2^31 (could go up to 2^53):

```
=BASE(2^31+(-12457896),2,32)  # returns 011111111010000011110100001011000
```

**For either positive or negative**, both formulas could be coupled in a single IF formula.  Here are two ways you could do it that give the same answer, where MyNum is the decimal number you start with:

```
=IF(MyNum<0, BASE(2^31+MyNum, 2, 32), BASE(MyNum, 2, 32))
```

or

```
=BASE(IF(MyNum<0, MyNum+2^32, MyNum), 2, 32)
```

Comment: `BASE' is not available in Excel 2011 for Mac, even though this page says it should be: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ie/office/base-function-2ef61411-aee9-4f29-a811-1c42456c6342. At least not for Excel for Mac 2011 version 14.7.7, which I tested now.

Comment: `BASE` works for Excel 2013+, great!

Comment: Note this drops leading '0' so you need to stuff.

Comment: @Jamie BASE will pad with zeros if you add a third argument, e.g. `=BASE(15,2,10)` gives result `0000001111`.

Answer (score 11):

See VBA posted [here](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/578667-use-dec2bin-function-visual-basic-applications-edit-macro.html)

```
' The DecimalIn argument is limited to 79228162514264337593543950245
' (approximately 96-bits) - large numerical values must be entered
' as a String value to prevent conversion to scientific notation. Then
' optional NumberOfBits allows you to zero-fill the front of smaller
' values in order to return values up to a desired bit level.
Function DecToBin(ByVal DecimalIn As Variant, Optional NumberOfBits As Variant) As String
  DecToBin = ""
  DecimalIn = CDec(DecimalIn)
  Do While DecimalIn <> 0
    DecToBin = Trim$(Str$(DecimalIn - 2 * Int(DecimalIn / 2))) & DecToBin
    DecimalIn = Int(DecimalIn / 2)
  Loop
  If Not IsMissing(NumberOfBits) Then
    If Len(DecToBin) > NumberOfBits Then
      DecToBin = "Error - Number too large for bit size"
    Else
      DecToBin = Right$(String$(NumberOfBits, "0") & _
      DecToBin, NumberOfBits)
    End If
  End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 5):

I just tried the formula above, and found that Microsoft screwed up the DEC2BIN function in another way that keeps the formula from working correctly with negative numbers. Internally, DEC2BIN uses a ten bit result; leading zeroes are dropped from the text result, unless the optional length parameter is used, in which case the required number of leading zeroes are left in the string. But here's the rub: a negative number always starts with a one, so there are no leading zeroes to drop, so DEC2BIN will always show all ten bits! Thus, DEC2BIN(-1,8), which should show 11111111 (eight ones) will instead show 1111111111 (ten ones.)

To fix this, use RIGHT to trim each eight bit chunk to eight bits, dumb as that sounds.

```
=RIGHT(DEC2BIN(QUOTIENT(A1,256^3),8),8) & RIGHT(...
```

(I read through the VBA, and it does not have the same problem, but it doesn't look like it will handle negatives at all.)

Answer (score 3):

To add easier to read formatting to Taosique's great answer, you can also break it up into chunks of 4 bits with spaces in between, although the formula grows to be a monster:

```
=DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT($A$1,16^7),16),4)&" "&DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT($A$1,16^6),16),4)&" "&DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT($A$1,16^5),16),4)&" "&DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT($A$1,16^4),16),4)&" "&DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT($A$1,16^3),16),4)&" "&DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT($A$1,16^2),16),4)&" "&DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT($A$1,16^1),16),4)&" "&DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT($A$1,16^0),16),4)

1101 0100 1111 0110 0011 0001 0000 0001
```

Of course, you can just use the right half of it, if you're just interested in 16 bit numbers:

```
=DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT($A$1,16^3),16),4)&" "&DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT($A$1,16^2),16),4)&" "&DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT($A$1,16^1),16),4)&" "&DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT($A$1,16^0),16),4)

0011 0001 0000 0001
```

Comment: It's easier and clearer to use Excel's TEXT function:


    =TEXT( DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT(A1,256^3),256),8) & DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT(A1,256^2),256),8) & DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT(A1,256^1),256),8) & DEC2BIN(MOD(QUOTIENT(A1,256^0),256),8), "00000 0000 000 00 0")


This also makes it easy to break it into different length chunks separated by spaces simply by placing the spaces where you want them in the text string.  For example, if A1 contains 14,163, the text string "00000 0000 000 00 0" would give 
    01101 1101 010 01 1

Comment: Can't seem to get the formatting in the above post...  I'd like to look like the comment immediately above.
Can someone tell me how?

Answer (score 1):

While I didn't write this for negatives or decimals, it should be relatively easy to modify. This VBA will convert any super large (or not so large if you want, but that wasn't the point) decimal up to the converted binary result containing up to 32767 digits (maximum string length in VBA).

Enter decimal in cell "A1" as a string, result will be in "B1" as a string.

```
Dim NBN As String

Dim Bin As String

5 Big = Range("A1")

AA = Len(Big)

For XX = 1 To AA

L1 = Mid(Big, XX, 1) + CRY

CRY = 0

If L1 = 0 Then

FN = "0"

GoTo 10

End If

If Int(L1 / 2) = L1 / 2 Then

FN = L1 / 2

GoTo 10

End If

If Int(L1 / 2) <> L1 / 2 Then

FN = Int(L1 / 2)

CRY = 10

GoTo 10

End If

10 NBN = NBN & FN

Next XX

If Left(NBN, 1) = "0" Then

NBN = Right(NBN, (Len(NBN) - 1))

End If

If CRY = 10 Then Bin = "1" & Bin Else Bin = "0" & Bin

Range("A1") = NBN

Range("A2") = Bin

If Len(NBN) > 0 Then

NBN = ""

CRY = 0

GoTo 5

End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Someone can find binary shift operations more clear and relevant here

```
=DEC2BIN(BITRSHIFT($A$1,24),8) & DEC2BIN(MOD(BITRSHIFT($A$1,16),256),8) & DEC2BIN(MOD(BITRSHIFT($A$1,8),256),8) & DEC2BIN(MOD($A$1,256),8)
```

This formula is for 32-bit values

Answer (score 1):

This vba function solves the problem of binary conversion of numbers greater than 511 that can not be done with WorksheetFunction.dec2bin.
The code takes advantage of the WorksheetFunction.dec2bin function by applying it in pieces.

```
Function decimal2binary(ByVal decimal2convert As Long) As String
Dim rest As Long
If decimal2convert = 0 Then
   decimal2binary = "0"
   Exit Function
End If
Do While decimal2convert > 0
   rest = decimal2convert Mod 512
   decimal2binary = Right("000000000" + WorksheetFunction.Dec2Bin(rest), 9) + decimal2binary
   decimal2convert = (decimal2convert - rest) / 512
Loop
decimal2binary = Abs(decimal2binary)
End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Code-only answers are discouraged, as they provide no insight into how the problem was solved. Please update your solution to include an explanation of how your code solves the problem at hand :)

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(Decimal>-1,BASE(Decimal,2,32),BASE(2^32+(Decimal),2))
```

Does both positive and negative numbers.
Took a bit LOL. Tech pun.
You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Without VBA and working with negative numbers as well (here: sint16), however, taking much more space:

[image: Screenshot of the "int16 bits to decimal.xlsx" excel sheet]

You can download the excel file here: (sorry, didn't know where to put the file)
[int16 bits to decimal.xlsx](https://files.ml-cloud.de/s/xaWd45tozEzGyKf)

or alternatively follow these steps (if your Excel is not in English, use [Excel Translator](https://en.excel-translator.de/translator/) to "translate" the formula into your MS Office language):

1. Enter the binary number in 4-bit nibbles (A4 = most significant to D4 = least significant) like shown in the screenshot. Enter all 4 digits (even if starting with 0) and format them as "text"
2. Enter formula in F4:

```
    =IF(NUMBERVALUE(A4)>=1000,TRUE,FALSE)
```

3. Enter the letter "A" in G2-J2, "B" in K2-N2, "C" in O2-R2, "D" in S2-V2
4. Enter "1" in G3, K3, O3 and S3; "2" in H3, L3, P3 and T3; "3" in I3, M3, Q3 and U3; "4" in J3, N3, R3 and V3
5. In G4, enter:

```
    =MID(INDIRECT(G$2&ROW()),G$3,1)
```

6. Copy the formula to H4-V4
7. In X4, enter:

```
    =IF(G4="1",0,1)
```

8. Copy X4 to Y4-AM4
9. In BD3 enter "1"
10. In BC4, enter:

```
    =IF((AM$4+BD3)=2,1,0)
```

11. IN BD4, enter:

```
    =IF((AM$4+BD3)=2,0,IF((AM$4+BD3)=1,1,0))
```

12. Copy BD4 and BD4 and insert it 15 times diagonally one row further down and one column further left (like in the screenshot), i.e. insert it to BB5 and BC5, then BA6 and BB6, ..., AN19 and AO19.
13. In AO20, enter "=AO19"; in AP20, enter "=AP18" and so on until BD20 ("=BD4") - i.e. bring down the numbers into one line as seen in the screenshot
14. In BE20, enter (this is your result):

```
    =IF(F4=FALSE,BIN2DEC(A4&B4)*2^8+BIN2DEC(C4&D4),-1*(BIN2DEC(AO20&AP20&AQ20&AR20&AS20&AT20&AU20&AV20)*2^8+BIN2DEC(AW20&AX20&AY20&AZ20&BA20&BB20&BC20&BD20)))
```

Answer (score -2):

There maybe a simple solution.   I have several 4.2 billion cells that are actually a negative Two's Complement and this works to get the correct value:
=SUM(2^31-(A1-2^31))