# Run-time error 1004: Application-defined or object-defined error in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to convert a column of values from Decimal to Binary and for some reason I get this error. I'm new to VBA coding so i might be missing on some basic information.

The code I have:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim r As Range
Dim myRange As Range: Set myRange = Range("E2:E2000") 'define your range
Dim rcopy As Range
Dim myCopyRange As Range: Set myCopyRange = Range("P2:P2000") 'range for the converted values

For i = 1 To myRange.Cells.Count
    myCopyRange.Cells(i).Value = WorksheetFunction.Dec2Bin(myRange.Cells(i).Value)
Next
End Sub
```

My E column with the values that must be converted is set on Number format, and my P column is set right now on Text. However I tried changing the format of the columns to Number or General and I keep on getting the same error.

Thank you for the help:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a few things:

1). Dec2Bin can't handle numbers larger than 511 and will throw a 1004Error if you try to do so.

2). You might want to use long variable for numbers, there is no point really to use integer.

3). Another way in doing this would be like:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Long, LR as Long

With Sheets(1)
    LR = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To LR
        If .Cells(i, 5).value < 512 then .Cells(i, 16).Value = WorksheetFunction.Dec2Bin(.Cells(i, 5).value)
    Next i
End with

End Sub
```

**EDIT**

You could also opt to include a formula in your loop that will work with 32bit like so:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Long, LR As Long

With Sheets(1)
    LR = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To LR
        .Cells(i, 16).Formula = "=DEC2BIN(E" & i & "/512^3,5) & DEC2BIN(INT(MOD(E" & i & ",512^3)/512^2),9) & DEC2BIN(INT(MOD(E" & i & ",512^2)/512),9) & DEC2BIN(MOD(E" & i & ",512),9)"
    Next
End With

End Sub
```

**EDIT2**

For a dynamic sized bitnumber, you might want to use a UDF. See below:

```
Function DecToBin(ByVal DecimalIn As Variant, Optional NumberOfBits As Variant) As String

DecToBin = ""
DecimalIn = CDec(DecimalIn)
Do While DecimalIn <> 0
    DecToBin = Trim$(Str$(DecimalIn - 2 * Int(DecimalIn / 2))) & DecToBin
    DecimalIn = Int(DecimalIn / 2)
Loop
If Not IsMissing(NumberOfBits) Then
    If Len(DecToBin) > NumberOfBits Then
        DecToBin = "Error - Number too large for bit size"
    Else
        DecToBin = Right$(String$(NumberOfBits, "0") & _
        DecToBin, NumberOfBits)
    End If
End If

End Function
```

And this is how you incorporate this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Long, LR as Long

With Sheets(1)
    LR = .Range("E" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To LR
        .Cells(i, 16).Value = "'" & DecToBin(.Cells(i, 5).value)
    Next i
End with

End Sub
```

Here is a usefull [Link](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/578667-use-dec2bin-function-vba-edit-macro.html)

You could also just call the function from your worksheet typing this formule:

```
=DecToBin(E1)
```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you for the help! however I have to concert numbers greater than 511... is there any workaround about this? I tried converting the number to Hex at first and Dec2Hex is working... but afterwards the Hex2Bin still doesn't work and gives me the same error.

Comment: I will add an option to include a formula that will work with 32bit though a loop. For more options I want to redirect you to this page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24387894/decimal-to-binary-conversion-for-large-numbers-in-excel

Comment: The 32bit loop seems to be working but can you please explain me a bit what the code does besides splitting the number in groups of 9bit and 5bit? Also if my number is 19bit, can i do a group of 10bit and one of 9bit only? I'm sorry for bothering you with this many questions. Thank you so much!

Comment: Well, what you need then is a function, I found one that I will include in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub test()
    Dim i

    For i = 2 To 2000
        Cells(i, "P").Value = Application.Dec2Bin(Cells(i, "E").Value)
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

`Dec2Bin` only accepts numbers, otherwise it throws 1004. So you should check the type of the value before passing it to `Dec2Bin`, like this:

```
If Typename(myRange.Cells(i).Value)="Double" Then ...
```

Typename returns `Double` for numbers, other values can be String, Date, Empty.