# Using permutations to sort stochastic vectors

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create a stochastic vector collection (VBA) with the following characteristics: a) each vector is a 10-dimension array; b) all non-null components of the vector are the same value. The collection must have all the possible vectors in this conditions.

I started doing this by adding vectors one by one to the collection like this:

```
Dim DB As New Collection: Set DB = New Collection
'First set:
    DB.Add Array(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    DB.Add Array(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    DB.Add Array(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    ...
    DB.Add Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)
'Second set:
    DB.Add Array(1/2, 1/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    DB.Add Array(1/2, 0, 1/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    DB.Add Array(1/2, 0, 0, 1/2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    ...
    DB.Add Array(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1/2, 1/2)
'Third set:
    DB.Add Array(1/3, 1/3, 1/3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    DB.Add Array(1/3, 1/3, 0, 1/3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
    ...
```

And so on until get the last vector (which constitutes the entire tenth set):

```
...
'Tenth set:
    DB.Add Array(1/10, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10, 1/10)
```

Well, as you may know, the collection will end up to have 1023 vectors, so my question is very simple (I believe the question is the only simple thing): Is there a way to do this without writing explicitly all the 1023 vectors?

Let me show you what I got so far:

First of all, I can get the result by getting the same arrays with 1's instead of the fraction components.

Second, I can't do it for the first set itself. How do I can make something like

```
For x = 0 to 9
    DB.Add Array(x, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Next x
```

work to give the result I pretend? Please note that I know the last bit of code doesn't give me the first set of vectors... It's just to give you an idea  of what I'm asking.

On third place, I think once I get help with the problem for the first set, I'm capable of doing the same for the others. Non the less, if you're eager to help me doing all the script to the tenth set, who am I to say no, eh eh!

I know it's a little tricky this one! Any help will be very appreciated. And, as always, thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve your problem like this:

- For each 'set' the number of array combinations is given by [N Choose K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient) where N is 10 and K is the Nth number of the set.
- We can get total number of combinations by summing 10 Choose 1 + 10 Choose 2 + 10 Choose 3 etc all the way to 10 Choose 10. This adds to 1023 as you already observed.
- Consider each array to be a binary string of 10 0s and 1s then you can loop 1 to 1023 and get the 10-digit binary equivalent of that decimal number - which will count all the way from 0000000001 to 1111111111.
- Get the binary number as a string and count the 1s in the string. The number of 1s gives you the set that the number belongs to e.g. for three 1s means the array would be in your third set per your example.
- Loop over each character in the string and for each 1 add the reciprocal of the number of 1s you counted to the array in that slot. E.g. if there are three 1s then each array slot gets 1/3. For each 0, add 0 to that slot. This ensures the items in the array add to 1.
- Add the array to the collection, and loop

Sample code below - I commented a couple of links to code that is useful for this task:

- [N Choose K with VB.NET](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_calculate_n_choose_k.html) (ports to VBA very easily)
- [DecToBin for larger numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109116/using-dec2bin-with-large-numbers) (better than `WorksheetFunction.Dec2Bin`)

Code:

```
Option Explicit

Sub BuildStochasticArray()

    Dim coll As Collection
    Dim lngSlots As Long
    Dim lngCombinations As Long
    Dim lng1 As Long
    Dim strBin As String
    Dim lngNumberOfOnes As Long
    Dim lng2 As Long
    Dim var As Variant
    Dim dblSum As Double

    Set coll = New Collection
    ' you have 10 slots
    lngSlots = 10
    ' you have this many combinations - 1023 for 10
    lngCombinations = GetTotalCombinations(lngSlots, lngSlots)

    For lng1 = 1 To lngCombinations
        'get binary representation with 0 padding upto lngSlots
        strBin = DecToBin(lng1, lngSlots)
        'count number of 1s - this will define you fraction
        lngNumberOfOnes = Len(strBin) - Len(Replace(strBin, "1", ""))
        'create the set
        ReDim var(1 To lngSlots) As Double
        For lng2 = 1 To lngSlots
            If Mid$(strBin, lng2, 1) = "1" Then
                var(lng2) = 1 / lngNumberOfOnes
            Else
                var(lng2) = 0
            End If
        Next lng2
        'add to collection
        coll.Add var, strBin

    Next lng1

    ' test the procedure by iterating the collection and check each vector adds to 1
    For lng1 = 1 To lngCombinations
        var = coll.Item(lng1)
        ' round to 5 places because of floating point math
        dblSum = Round(Application.WorksheetFunction.Sum(var), 5)
        If dblSum <> 1 Then
            Debug.Print "Error at index " & lng1
        End If
    Next lng1

    Debug.Print "Collection items " & coll.Count

End Sub

Function GetTotalCombinations(n As Long, k As Long) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long
    For i = 1 To k
        j = j + NChooseK(n, i)
    Next i
    GetTotalCombinations = j
End Function

' http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_calculate_n_choose_k.html
Function NChooseK(n As Long, k As Long) As Long
    Dim lngResult As Long
    Dim i As Long

    lngResult = 1
    For i = 1 To k
        lngResult = lngResult * (n - (k - i))
        lngResult = lngResult / i
    Next i

    NChooseK = lngResult

End Function

' https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109116/using-dec2bin-with-large-numbers
Function DecToBin(ByVal lngDec, lngNumberOfBits As Long) As String
    Dim strBin As String

    strBin = ""
    Do While lngDec <> 0
        strBin = Trim$(Str$(lngDec - 2 * Int(lngDec / 2))) & strBin
        lngDec = Int(lngDec / 2)
    Loop

    strBin = Right$(String$(lngNumberOfBits, "0") & strBin, lngNumberOfBits)

    DecToBin = strBin

End Function
```

Comment: Great answer! I totally got your strategy! Actually, I got it so well that I don't even need the code you post! Thank you so much for your answer! Later I'll post my approach to the problem! Once again, thank you very much :)

Comment: Thanks - because you are looking for arrays with either 0 or something, you can probably get away with the total combinations being `(2^N)-1` where `N` is the number of slots.

Comment: Yes! That I know! That's useful maybe if I ever need to make the array dimension variable. However, for now, I need this just for 10-dimension arrays. So it's always 1023...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @Robin Mackenzie I managed to find a way of writing a simple code to create the array collection I pretended. Here's my way of doing it just for future reference:

```
Dim DB As New Collection: Set DB = New Collection
Dim X01 As Integer, X02 As Integer, X03 As Integer, X04 As Integer, X05 As Integer
Dim X06 As Integer, X07 As Integer, X08 As Integer, X09 As Integer, X10 As Integer
Dim CODE As String: Dim SUM As Integer
For x = 1 To 1023
    CODE = DecToBin(x)
    X01 = Val(Mid(Format(CODE, "0000000000"), 1, 1))
    X02 = Val(Mid(Format(CODE, "0000000000"), 2, 1))
    X03 = Val(Mid(Format(CODE, "0000000000"), 3, 1))
    X04 = Val(Mid(Format(CODE, "0000000000"), 4, 1))
    X05 = Val(Mid(Format(CODE, "0000000000"), 5, 1))
    X06 = Val(Mid(Format(CODE, "0000000000"), 6, 1))
    X07 = Val(Mid(Format(CODE, "0000000000"), 7, 1))
    X08 = Val(Mid(Format(CODE, "0000000000"), 8, 1))
    X09 = Val(Mid(Format(CODE, "0000000000"), 9, 1))
    X10 = Val(Mid(Format(CODE, "0000000000"), 10, 1))
    SUM = X01 + X02 + X03 + X04 + X05 + X06 + X07 + X08 + X09 + X10
    DB.Add Array(X01 / SUM, X02 / SUM, X03 / SUM, X04 / SUM, X05 / SUM, X06 / SUM, X07 / SUM, X08 / SUM, X09 / SUM, X10 / SUM)
Next x
```

The `DecToBin` function is available on  [DecToBin for larger numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22109116/using-dec2bin-with-large-numbers) as mentioned by @Robin Mackenzie.